# ASP.Net MVC: Upgrading from 3.5 to 4.0, Problem with Enumerable Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've just ran into a big gotcha with upgrading an ASP.Net MVC app from 3.5 to 4.0.  The following code works fine in 3.5, but when run in 4.0 fails with the error below:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Estam.Web.Models.Account.SupplierBuyerViewModel>>" %>
<ul><%
    foreach (var buyer in Model)
    {
%><li>
    <%if (buyer.CanFeedback)
     { %>
    <a href="#" class="rateButton rateBuyer" name="<%=buyer.BuyerName%>" id="id_<%=buyer.BuyerId %>">
        Rate</a>
    <%} %>
    <%=buyer.BuyerName%>
</li>
<%
    }
%>
</ul>
```

The error:

**Unable to create a constant value of type 'Estam.Models.BuyerModel'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. Here's the Model code

```
using System;

namespace Estam.Web.Models.Account
{
    public class SupplierBuyerViewModel
    {
        public Guid BuyerId { get; set; }
        public string BuyerName { get; set; }
        public bool CanFeedback { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryContactEmail { get; set; }

        public double Variance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: 3.5 and 4.0 are .NET versions. Which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: What does Estam.Models.BuyerModel relate to, since the control is bound to Estam.Web.Models.Account.SupplierBuyerViewModel? Can we see the Model code, too?

Comment: The site was created with ASP.Net 3.5, so I'm assuming the ASP.Net MVC version is 2.0.  All I changed is the compilation target from 3.5 to 4.0.

Comment: I don't think this is an error in the View. Agree with @Steve Morgan. Need to see your model code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an Entity Framework error, so you need to go back to your database model or data access code.

Are you trying to cast an enum inside a Linq-to-Entities query? If so, try to cast it outside the query, if you can.

Comment: None of the properties of the model are an enum.

Comment: OK, but I think it's possibly still related to Linq. Can we see your data access code?

Comment: What part of the data access do you want to see?  The SupplierBuyerViewModel is a simple class that doesn't have anything to do with the Entity Framework.  It is populated in a couple of controllers and is referenced by other ViewModels.

Comment: OK, we're kind of flying blind, here. The error message that you received talks about Estam.Models.BuyerModel. You've not shown us any kind of relationship between that and SupplierBuyerViewModel, but my suspicion is that when the model is being prepared for the View, *something* is doing *something* with BuyerModel. I presume this isn't a compile-time error. Have you tried stepping through with the debugger? How about we see a stack trace?

Comment: Hmm, looking at BuyerModel led me to looking at another model, and it is very complex including some read only collections.  This is probably where my problem is.  I will dig into it further from there.